# How to make XTemplate work with TabPanel in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

I've got my TabPanels generating as expected, however, if I try and inject an `XTemplate` into one of the panels, and then call `content.update(myArray);`, the result is that the panels don't move, the buttons don't work, and the template doesn't render.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.setup({
        onReady: function () {
            var rootPanel,
                videoPanel,
                aboutPanel,
                videoTpl,
                bergman,
                gray,
                videosToShow

            bergman = { id: "23657322" };
            gray = { id: "23694183" };
            videosToShow = [bergman, gray];

            videoTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">',
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{id}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=80ceff" ',
                'width="400" ',
                'height="225" ',
                'frameborder="0">',
                '</iframe>',
                '</tpl>'
            );

            videoPanel = {
                title: "Videos",
                tpl: videoTpl,
                iconCls: "tv",
                badgeText: "1",
                dockedItems: [{ xtype: "toolbar", title: "Videos"}],
                scroll: "vertical"
            };

            aboutPanel = {
                title: "About",
                html: "About RockPointe Church.",
                iconCls: "more",
                dockedItems: [{ xtype: "toolbar", title: "About"}],
                scroll: "vertical"
            };

            rootPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
                fullscreen: true,
                layout: 'card',
                items: [videoPanel, aboutPanel],
                tabBar: { dock: 'bottom' }
            });

            content.update(videosToShow);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

I needed to `videoPanel.update(videosToShow);`

I also had to change
`videoPanel = {`
to
`videoPanel = new Panel({`

Comment: The `content.update(videosToShow);` bit was simply because I was following the video tutorial while trying to make my own custom panel. **Note To Self:** Follow the tutorial to the letter.